# PCharts labeling X-axis

Tags: php, pchart

Would it be possible to just label the x axis by the minimum value and the maximum value instead of having values inbetween?

More info on what I'm graphing:
I have a large dataset of dates that I am graphing. Currently I am scaling it to a scale of 0-100 to graph it. I just want to label 0 as the lowest date and 100 as the highest date.

Comment: Just suggesting an alternative charting tool... Highcharts is my charting tool of choice just now for all charty needs.

Comment: @Brian Thanks for the suggestion but I was looking for a charting tool that process the data on the server to return an image. I will be sending the url via XML to be embedded on another page.

Comment: OK - depending on the access you have to you're server there is a couple of server-side wrappers that have been created for just that - http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/42-highcharts-on-the-server

Comment: @Brian which one would you recommend? The moxie group or the one2team They both look like they use java though. Is that correct?

Comment: The Moxie one I have used in the past... but you do need to be able to run Java... PChart is a decent solution too... I was merley pointing to alternatives just 'cos I think the charts Highcharts create are some of the nicest around! Honestly for ease of development probably sticking with pchart is best... it's just personal choice really. With you're actual q tho... I am rusty with pchart but Aaron's comment below should do.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion though. I agree as highcharts do look really nice. I will keep it in mind for other projects where I would need a chart!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [`setFixedScale()`](http://pchart.sourceforge.net/documentation.php?topic=pChart#)

```
$Test->setFixedScale(0,100,1);
```

That will show `0` as the min and then `100` as the max

Comment: Would that affect how the graph is drawn with the dataset?

Comment: @Dan You want to set the `min` and `max` parameters to what you want it to scale too, then the third param is how many divisions on the X-Axis

Comment: The problem is that I took the dataset of dates, converted them in respect to 0-100, where 0 is the lowest date, and 100 is the highest date and then plotted that date. I want to display the high date at where the 100 would be and the 0 where the lowest date would be.